# Create a new string column on the table with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

Hope you're doing well, I actually have a php function who's Create a new integer (4-byte) column on the table, instead I would like my function create a string column on my MariaDB table.

Thanks (if you need more infos I stay around all the day long)

```
  /**
 * Create a new integer (4-byte) column on the table.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
 * @param  bool  $unsigned
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
    public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
{
    return $this->addColumn('integer', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
}
```

Here's the code reffering to the code under this post:

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateConsultantsTable extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('consultants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('business_id')
            ->references('id')->on('businesses');

        $table->string('trigram')->unique();

        $table->date('availability')
            ->nullable();

        $table->integer('years_experience')->nullable();
```

Comment: For info when  I put a string in the form controlled by this function I have that  error in my console: `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with Laravel it's pretty easy.

Here you can see how to generate a migration for doing this approach

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#generating-migrations

So let's say you'd like to add a shortname field to a *users* - table

```
php artisan make:migration add_shortname_to_users_table --table=users
```

Open the `2017_12_04_104053_add_shortname_to_users_table.php` (the date before will be another)

So, at last just update the *up* - method

```
$table->string('shortname');
```

Run your normal migration and you're done

Comment: may I delete the existing code `   $table->foreign('business_id')
` according to my update post under?

Comment: if i delete the code it will automaticly delate the column or it will let an empty colum in the table?

Comment: it will ignore if, if you'd like to delete a column, you've to create a new migration (or use the existing from above) and run: ```$table->dropColumn('business_id');```